# TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '${id}' from '${id}'

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to pass javascript variables into the URL template in my ajax call within my script tag but it keeps telling me that it could not parse the remainder. Any idea how it should be?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: `{% url 'posts:toggle-reaction' object_id=${id} object_type=${type} %}`,
            data: serializedData,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (response) {
                // alert the error if any error occured
                alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Been a while since I used jquery, but what are `${id}` and `${type}` supposed to do here? Where are those values from?

Comment: As in the [`${var}` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? They're like f-strings but for JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

The `{% url %}` templatetag is processed before the JavaScript is. In other words, Django thinks `${id}` is a variable that you're trying to pass to the templatetag in reversing the `posts:toggle-reaction` URL and falls over.

Without seeing your urls.py file or where the `id` and `type` JavaScript variables are coming from, it looks like what you're trying to achieve is:

```
url: `{% url 'posts:toggle-reaction' %}?object_id=${id}&object_type=${type}`,
```

#### Edit

As far as I'm aware there's no easy way to reverse a URL with keyword arguments for use in JavaScript. This would work, but feels dirty:

```
`{% url 'posts:toggle-reaction' object_id=9998 object_type=9999 %}`.replace(9998, id).replace(9999, type)
```

It would at least help avoid hard-coding the URL.

Comment: if my url in the urls.py is 
```
path('<int:object_id>/<str:object_type>/reaction/', views.toggle_reaction, name='toggle-reaction') 
```
how can I include the variables without it being a querystring?

Comment: Thought that might be the case. See my edit